# How to find all the pages on my site with URLs all start with this same prefix

Tags: google-search, url

I am trying to search for all URLs on my site that start with

```
http://www.neduet.edu.pk/examination/NED/results/~
```

How do I do that using Google search?

I have tried

```
inurl:http://www.neduet.edu.pk/examination/NED/results/
site:http://www.neduet.edu.pk/examination/NED/results/
```

but both do not work.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=site:http://www.neduet.edu.pk+inurl:/examination/&safe=off&prmd=inv&filter=0&biw=360&bih=600

Answer (score 5):

You are using the `site` and `inurl` operators incorrectly.

Start with the `site` operator, and add your domain name without `http/s` and `www` prefix:

```
site:neduet.edu.pk
```

Then use `inurl` to specify the URL string that you would like all results include:

```
inurl:/examination/NED/results/
```

then add them together:

```
site:neduet.edu.pk inurl:/examination/NED/results/
```